# Получение всех сущностей с помощью JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity

Сущность:

```
package com.igorgorbunov3333.core.entities.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by Игорь on 03.04.2016.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "cases")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "findAllCases", query = "SELECT c FROM Case c JOIN c.client JOIN c.firstInstance " +
            "JOIN c.secondInstance JOIN c.thirdInstance JOIN c.category"),
})
public class Case {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "case_number")
    private String caseNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "first_instance_id")
    private FirstInstance firstInstance;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "second_instance_id")
    private SecondInstance secondInstance;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "third_instance_id")
    private ThirdInstance thirdInstance;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "closing_date")
    private Date closingDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    private float price;
    .....
```

Как видите есть именованый запрос `findAllCases`.
Получаю все сущности (`Case`) так:

```
public List<Case> findAll() {
    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findAllCases");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Но метод возвращает все сущности, в которых поля `secondInstance`, `thirdInstance` **не нулевые**. Как сделать так, что бы возвращались и сущности с нулевыми полями `secondInstance` и `thirdInstance`?

Comment: Убрать `JOIN c.secondInstance JOIN c.thirdInstance`. Вообще убрать все join. На фига они нужны, если хотите получить всё? Ведь join ограничивает выборку только теми энтитями, у которых есть соответствующие энтити в join (не нулевые).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `SQL` есть разные виды объединений таблиц (`JOIN`-ов), в Вашем случае интересны два из них

1. `INNER JOIN`: при отсутствии записи в присоединённой таблице, запись из основной таблицы не попадает в результирующую выборку
2. `LEFT JOIN`: запись из основной таблицы попадает в результирующую выборку независимо от наличия записи в присоединённой таблице

В языке `JPQL` оператор `JOIN` по умолчанию работает как `INNER JOIN`, поэтому в Вашем случае из выборки выпадают записи, для которых не найдены записи в `secondInstance` и `thirdInstance`. Для того, чтобы в выборку по сущности `Case` попадали записи с пустыми `secondInstance` и `thirdInstance` следует явно указать `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Все понятно, спасибо!